# Interactive slider with multiple controls in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter

In a Jupyter notebook, I would like to make an interactive slider with two control points. It's easy to do with a single control [see this example](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html):

[image]

But here's an example of what I really want, it is called an ***interval slider*** (Mathematica does this nicely):

[image]

Is this possible to do with [ipywidgets](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets) or some perhaps other python package?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're getting at is to have arbitrarily many sliders on the same bar, which is what I found this post while looking for, but [range sliders](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#FloatRangeSlider) do exist (at least they do now; this question is four years old).

```
widgets.FloatRangeSlider(
    value=[5, 7.5],
    min=0,
    max=10.0,
    step=0.1,
    description='Test:',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    readout=True,
    readout_format='.1f',
)
```

(illustrative snippet stolen directly from linked doc)